# Batch script calling powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-scripting

I have a powershell script `gather_objects_from_csv.ps1` which is being scheduled through cmd. I'm using this command:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'e:\admin\gather_objects_from_csv.ps1'"
```

to call the powershell script, but it's throwing error for the line in the script

```
# create an empty hash which will hold a number of smaller hashes, of member details supplied in the csv, then piped to nw_sync_employees_8.ps1
$employees_list = @{}

# import the config.xml file containing the relevant user data, username/password etc...
$config = Import-CliXML nw-config.xml

# import some detail from the "normal" Newsweaver config file
$API_user = $config["API_USER"]
$API_user_password = $config["API_PASSWORD"]
$USE_PROXY = $config["USE_PROXY"]
$verboseMode = $config["VERBOSE_MODE"]

$account_code = $config["ACCOUNT_CODE"]
$source_file = $config["CSV_PATH"]

# check to see if the source file actually exists first
if (-Not (Test-Path $source_file)) {
    # if the source file can't be found, there isn't much value in continuing
    Write-Host -foregroundcolor red "Could not find specified source file. Check the path, permissions or location of source file specified: " $source_file
    Exit
}

# import the source file with a specified delimiter (it is a comma as it is a CSV file which is being imported)
# pipe "|" the csv to a forEach - Object loop to iterate throught the file row by row
$HashTableData = Import-CSV $source_file -Delimiter ',' |`

# ForEach - Object - iterates over each row of the csv

 ForEach-Object {

# Empty hash $memberDetails, this will be populated with the information from the csv
  $memberDetails = @{}


    $EmployeeID = "$($_.EmployeeID)".Trim()
    $FirstName = "$($_.LegalFirstName)".Trim()
    $LastName = "$($_.LegalLastName)".Trim()
    $LegalNameinGeneralDisplayFormat = "$($_.LegalNameinGeneralDisplayFormat)".Trim()
    $LegalNameinLocalScript = "$($_.LegalNameinLocalScript)".Trim()



    #set the email address as the key for the hashtable $employees_list
    #and the value of this "hash of hashes" is the hash table created above ie. memberDetails (csv information)
    $employees_list.Set_Item("$($Email)", $memberDetails)

 }

 # pass/ pipe the hash called $employees_list to the nw_sync script with the relevant parameters
 $employees_list | ./nw_sync_employees.ps1 -account_code $account_code -password $API_user_password -user $API_user -permission 'All'

 exit
```

Error line:

> ```
> nw_sync_employees.ps1: The term ./nw_sync_employees.ps1' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, of if a path was included,
> verify that the path is correct and try again. 
> + $employee_list | ./nw_sync_employees.ps1 -account_code $account_cod...
> +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>             +CategoryInfo         : ObjectNotFound:
> (.\nw_sync_employees.ps1:String)[], CommandNotFoundException
>             +FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
> ```

powershell script is calling another ps script located in the same folder. When ran through powershell terminal, the same script is not throwing any error. But when I'm trying to call it through commandline it is throwing error.

Comment: Why are you not using the `-File` option? Aren't you using at least PowerShell v2.0?

Comment: What does "__being scheduled through cmd__" actually mean? You can call Powershell.exe directly without the need for cmd.

Comment: Windows uses backslashes for directory separators too, so I assume `./nw_sync_employees.ps1` should be `.\nw_sync_employees.ps1`!

Comment: I would advise that you provide the code/content of the PowerShell script generating the error message. The command which is running the script isn't the source of your problem, _(as you can clearly see that it runs the script it was asked to)_, therefore the batch-file tag is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @olaf Please can you help with the command how can you do with powershell, i'm not much familiar with powershell commands. All of our batch processing script are of .bat files. For the first time we need to schedule a powershell script.

Comment: @Compo  I've added code

Comment: Search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+get+script+directory . `./nw_sync_employees.ps1` is relative to the current directory, which may not the script directory where you say it is located.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the .bat works for me :

Powershell.exe "D:\myfolder\myfile.ps1"

with Administrator rights.